# Converting Hindi/Indian Number to Text Conversion to American Numbering

Tags: c#, windows

I am newbie here so please bear with me. I do need assistance in this matter but not doing the every bit for me. I can be as well interested in pseudo code manner of explanation if appropriate or if you want to fully convert it for me, well then I can be grateful.

I have searched google yes and I am getting different ways of converting and if i try implementing each in its own way, well my app does not run.

I have this sample code here that converts Numbers to text using the Hindi/Indian conversion methods.

Below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to return number in text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string NumberToText(int number)
    {
        // Converting the number to words
        if (number == 0) return "Zero";
        if (number == -2147483648) return "Minus Two Hundred and Fourteen Crore Seventy Four Lakh Eighty Three Thousand Six Hundred and Forty Eight";
        int[] num = new int[4];
        int first = 0;
        int u, h, t;
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        if (number < 0)
        {
            sb.Append("Minus ");
            number = -number;
        }
        string[] words0 = { "", "One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ", "Five ", "Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine " };
        string[] words1 = { "Ten ", "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ", "Fifteen ", "Sixteen ", "Seventeen ", "Eighteen ", "Nineteen " };
        string[] words2 = { "Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy ", "Eighty ", "Ninety " };
        string[] words3 = { "Thousand ", "Lakh ", "Crore " };
        num[0] = number % 1000; // units 
        num[1] = number / 1000;
        num[2] = number / 100000;
        num[1] = num[1] - 100 * num[2]; // thousands 
        num[3] = number / 10000000; // crores 
        num[2] = num[2] - 100 * num[3]; // lakhs 
        for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (num[i] != 0)
            {
                first = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = first; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (num[i] == 0) continue;
            u = num[i] % 10; // ones 
            t = num[i] / 10;
            h = num[i] / 100; // hundreds 
            t = t - 10 * h; // tens 
            if (h > 0) sb.Append(words0[h] + "Hundred ");
            if (u > 0 || t > 0)
            {
                if (h > 0 || i == 0) sb.Append(" ");
                if (t == 0)
                    sb.Append(words0[u]);
                else if (t == 1)
                    sb.Append(words1[u]);
                else
                    sb.Append(words2[t - 2] + words0[u]);
            }
            if (i != 0) sb.Append(words3[i - 1]);
        }
        return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to return number in text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string NumberToText(long number)
    {
        // Converting the number to words
        if (number == 0) return "Zero";
        if (number == -2147483648) return "Minus Two Hundred and Fourteen Crore Seventy Four Lakh Eighty Three Thousand Six Hundred and Forty Eight";
        long[] num = new long[4];
        long first = 0;
        long u, h, t;
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        if (number < 0)
        {
            sb.Append("Minus ");
            number = -number;
        }
        string[] words0 = { "", "One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ", "Five ", "Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine " };
        string[] words1 = { "Ten ", "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ", "Fifteen ", "Sixteen ", "Seventeen ", "Eighteen ", "Nineteen " };
        string[] words2 = { "Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy ", "Eighty ", "Ninety " };
        string[] words3 = { "Thousand ", "Lakh ", "Crore " };
        num[0] = number % 1000; // units 
        num[1] = number / 1000;
        num[2] = number / 100000;
        num[1] = num[1] - 100 * num[2]; // thousands 
        num[3] = number / 10000000; // crores 
        num[2] = num[2] - 100 * num[3]; // lakhs 
        for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (num[i] != 0)
            {
                first = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (long i = first; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (num[i] == 0) continue;
            u = num[i] % 10; // ones 
            t = num[i] / 10;
            h = num[i] / 100; // hundreds 
            t = t - 10 * h; // tens 
            try
            {
                if (h > 0) sb.Append(words0[h] + "Hundred ");
            }
            catch
            {
                //index out of range
            }
            if (u > 0 || t > 0)
            {
                if (h > 0 || i == 0) sb.Append(" ");//if (h > 0 || i == 0) sb.Append(" and");
                if (t == 0)
                    sb.Append(words0[u]);
                else if (t == 1)
                    sb.Append(words1[u]);
                else
                    sb.Append(words2[t - 2] + words0[u]);
            }
            if (i != 0) sb.Append(words3[i - 1]);
        }
        return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
    }
```

Now what I want or an explanation is how I can convert the available conversion to American conversion.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please can you be more clear about what input and output you expect, and state exactly what problems you have when it 'doesn't run'? Can you post error messages? Is there a segmentation fault? Does it fail at compilation?

Comment: generally the whole application is about accounting & financial calculations. The above code works correctly with no flaws but when it comes to writing checks, or reporting, the numbers are basically in hindi format which is inappropriate for us here in Kenya. Thats the basic issue

Comment: @jwg This is how it prints. 12,12,112 = Twelve lakh twelve thousand one hundred twelve whereas i need it to do this: 1,212,112 = One million, two hundred and twelve thousand one hundred and twelve.

Comment: you would have to describe the hindi format exactly, and the one you want, and then show how you try to achieve the conversation, and then if there is a problem, we can help you with that

Comment: Although it doesn't directly answer your question, it could be a good route for your to achieve the answer you want yourself: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18181/Test-Driven-First-Development-by-Example In the article I used the idea of translating numbers to a text format and slowly build up the ability as I write unit tests for them. You can do the same to slowly work to the solution that you want as we don't understand the number format you need.

Comment: I think if you have number than you can easily convert to American text. So is there issue that you have amount in Hindi text and you have to convert that in American. please specify